# How to visualize a map? (picture)

Tags: database, opengl, processing

I want to visualize a map like this: http://www.time.com/time/covers/20061030/where_we_live/.

Can I do this with opengl or processing? How?

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to do this is not in 3D, but just using basic isometric techniques and overpainting.

Take your map, scale it to half height to suggest perspective, and draw it on your canvas.

Now, create an empty transparent bitmap as large as the orginal map, and place pale pink circles with data as if on the map. Scale this bitmap to half height as well and draw it over the original map.

After this, create another, but make your circles 1 pixel smaller in radius, and shift the color one more tint toward dark red.  Scale it to half height again, and draw it over the existing composition, but one pixel higher in the y-direction. Keep repeating this step until the largest circle on your map reaches 0 radius so the highest peak is drawn.

I think that should create something very much like the map in the example, without needing complex 3D geometry.

Visually it would resemble the TIME map even more when:

-You use an inverse exponential formula to reduce the size of the circles every step. In the proposed algorithm, the spikes would be rather boringly linear (cone-shaped) and wouldn't get very high.

-You use the outline of the original map as a transparency mask to restrict each data layer. Do this before scaling to half height. This restricts your data spikes to the shape of the map, and prevents them spilling over the borders into the sea.

Of course this algorithm can be optimised by drawing the data layers at half height already using ellipses, and draw them directly over the map. The circle / layer way illustrates the basic technique better though, and makes it easier to do the outline restriction step.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would recommend using a grid of faces, culling against the map of the united states, then raising and colouring each point according to the scale featured in your link.

I think it'll actually be simpler then the method outlined by NielsK, the difficult part will just be getting the data you need in an easy to parse format.